# Scala - How to read a csv table into a RDD[Vector]

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, matrix, rdd

I would like to read from a huge csv file, assign every row to a vector via spliting values by ",". In the end I aim to have an RDD of Vectors which holds the values.
However I get an error after Seq:

type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.

My code is like this so far:

```
val file = "/data.csv"
val data: RDD[Vector] =sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    for(line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines){
      Vectors.dense(line.split (",").map (_.toDouble).distinct)
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read it using *sparkContext's textFile api* as

```
val file = "/data.csv"
val data = sc.textFile(file).map(line => Vectors.dense(line.split (",").map(_.toDouble).distinct))
```

And you should get `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]`

But if you are looking for `RDD[Vector[Double]]` then you can simply do

```
val file = "/data.csv"
val data = sc.textFile(file).map(line => line.split (",").map(_.toDouble).distinct.toVector)
```

Comment: Whit this way does it assign each line to a vector in rdd?

Comment: I tried first one and it actually works. However when I want to measure the correlation between vectors then I realized I must transpose the matrix since each vectors holds a record, not attributes. Is it possible to transpose?

Comment: when an answer works for you and is helpful to reach to your next step you should consider accepting the answer (and upvote too) and then ask another question for the next level errors.

Comment: but before you ask a question do a thorough research and try a lot yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that people do not answer next question without accept. Thanks for the information, I accepted it.